Как зарегистрировать акккаунт на сайте через post - запросы
я пытаюсь написать свой авторегер для сайта и при отправке на него запроса я получаю такую штуку: 
При отслеживании запросов я наблюдаю несколько запросов
сначала одно 
После другое:
Осмелюсь предположить, что я должен положить в upxToken  решения капчи, но как мне узнать токен капчи сначала при регистрации и сразу отправить в запросе ?
